# how to create one to one lookup relationship out of the box

Tags: lookup

While reading the trailhead documentation I came across

> lookup relationships can be one-to-one or one-to-many. The Account to Contact relationship is one-to-many because a single account can have many related contacts. For our DreamHouse scenario, you could create a one-to-one relationship between the Property object and a Home Seller object.

How is it possible out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many ways to achieve this.

---

One simple way can be:

Let say you have Object A Lookup in Object B. Create a Unique Text Field of length 18 in Object B. Use Record Trigger Flow to update this field with the ID value of the Lookup A.

When same A Lookup will be used for more than one B records, error will be thrown. So one A record can only be associated with one B record.

---

Comment: thank you for the answer.  but by default the look and master is always one to many right?

Comment: @prasanth Yes, by default both Lookup and Master-Detail are one to many.